# Creating layered JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm sure this is a simple question, but I can't find any information to help me, and I've been lost for a while.  I'm trying to create a JSON object, and here is what I have so far:

```
var myJsonObject = new Object();
myJsonObject.context.applicationName = appName;
myJsonObject.context.ID = ID;
myJsonObject.context.domain = domain;
myJsonObject.context.production = "no";

myJsonObject.other.name = userName;
myJsonObject.other.date = userDate;

var myString = JSON.stringify(myJsonObject);
```

and here is what I want my JSON string to look like.

```
{
"context": {
   "applicationName":"example",
   "ID":"exampleID",
   "domain":"someDomain",
   "production","no"
 },
"other": {
   "name":"userName1",
   "date":"userDate1"
 }
}
```

However, I keep getting `myJsonObject.context is undefined` errors.  I mean, I understand why it's happening, I never actually initialize it, but I don't know how to go about correcting this.  Any help would be appreciated.

I'm guessing the myJsonObject.context has to be initialized as another object, and then I just add it to my original object as an array of objects....is this correct?

Comment: points to all, because you are all right :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to first set it to an object, or you can just set them on the first line:

```
var myJsonObject = {context : {} , other: {} };
```

Comment: yeah, in a moment of dumb clarity, I added `myJsonObject.context = new Object();` and it worked.  I'll give you the answer, since you were right.

Answer (score 2):

Also note that you can define your objects using a shorter syntax, like so:

```
var myJsonObject = {
    context: {
        applicationName: appName,
        ID: ID,
        domain: domain,
        production: "no"
    },
    other: {
        name: userName,
        date: userDate
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm guessing the myJsonObject.context has to be initialized as another object

Yes

> and then I just add it to my original object

You'd generally do that at the same time

> as an array of objects

No. You have nothing resembling an array there.

```
var myJsonObject = {};
myJsonObject.context = {};
myJsonObject.context.applicationName = appName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Define `myJsonObject.context = {};` property first.